# How can I compare two arrays and run a function depending on the number of matching items (regardless of index)?

Tags: javascript

I had a previous solution with `.forEach` that didn't consider the fact that the answers can be selected in the wrong order, so the items at to be at the same exact index. If it was selected in the wrong order it wouldn't match (even though it was the right answer).

Now I'm trying a solution with `.every`, but it's not changing `score` when the button "check answers" is clicked. In case you'd like to check the entire code here it is (it's a bit too much to type in - I'm new to stackoverflow so lmk if a better method is suggested to share multiple components): https://replit.com/@arshia93/Quizzical#sections/QuizData.jsx

```
function scoreQuiz(allCorrectAnswers, selections) {
  let totalScore = 0;
  if(allCorrectAnswers.length === selections.length) {
    return allCorrectAnswers.every((element, index) => {
      element === selections[index] ? totalScore++ : totalScore
    })
    setScore(totalScore)  
  } 
  setFinished(!finished)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What alonealgorithm said is true that you should not return the `.every()` call, since you want to perform a state update after it is complete. However, I don't think `.every()` is the array method you want to use here. It will check every item and perform the `totalScore++`, but it is not the most declarative way to do so.

I would recommend using the [`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), since that is essentially what you're trying to do here. This should help you out:

```
const totalScore = selections.reduce((score, selection) => 
  score + (allCorrectAnswers.includes(selection) ? 1 : 0)
, 0);

setScore(totalScore);
```

**Note!** If it is possible for 2 questions to have the same answer option, then this will not work and incorrectly identify a correct answer. In order to accommodate for this, you would need to replace the selection at a particular index (rather than appending each one as it is selected), or match each selection to a question id.

Comment: thanks this is working now. I put the setScore in a function so it's calculated upon button click. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code in the replit you linked. I think the issue is at line 41 where you return the result of calling `every` method on your `allCorrectAnswers` array. So, after the `every` method is done executing you return the value `true` or `false` and you exit the scoreQuiz function **before** you reach the next line where you would have `setScore` for your quiz. So, you should remove the return statement and let the `setScore` and `setFinished` hooks execute.

Comment: Can you share what you mean with the code? I can't seem to make the needed changes.

Comment: Hello agm. On line 43 could you check what the value of totalScore is with a console.log statement inside of the `every()` method for every iteration and report back the result.

Comment: Line 43 is the every return statement so I did element === selections[index] ? console.log(totalScore++) : console.log(totalScore) it's returning a error